# RNN hidden value contains almost only 1 and -1

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using encoder-decoder model with RNN to generate the abstract for a document. After testing, I found that the outputs are totally useless, and they are all same. I printed the hidden value and found that it contains almost only 1 and -1.

Output of the decoder:

```python
['<SOS>', 'the', 'new', 'york', 'city', "'s", 'mother', 'was', 'found',      'in', 'the', 'world', 'cup', '.', 'the', 'former', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'yoselyn', 'is', 'the', 'the', 'much-loved', 'condition', '.', '<EOS>']
```

part of hidden value:

```python
( 0 ,.,.) = 

Columns 0 to 8 
   1.0000  0.9846 -1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000 -1.0000  0.0000  1.0000  1.0000

Columns 9 to 17 
  -1.0000  0.0000  1.0000 -1.0000 -0.9019  1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000 -1.0000

Columns 18 to 26 
   1.0000  1.0000  1.0000  1.0000 -1.0000  0.0000  1.0000  1.0000 -1.0000

Columns 27 to 35 
  -1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000

Columns 36 to 44 
   1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000  1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000  1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000
```

I'm a beginner in deep learning and I cannot understand why this happened. I checked my dataset and I think they are fine.

Encoder and decoder:

```python
class EncoderRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dict_size, hidden_size):
        super(EncoderRNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(dict_size, hidden_size)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(hidden_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, input_batch, input_batch_length, hidden):
        embedded = self.embedding(input_batch)
        packed_input = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, input_batch_length.cpu().numpy(), batch_first=True)
        output, hidden = self.gru(packed_input, hidden)
        return output, hidden


class DecoderRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, dict_size):
        super(DecoderRNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(dict_size, hidden_size)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(hidden_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, dict_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, target_batch, target_batch_length, hidden, train=False):
        embedded = self.embedding(target_batch)
        output = F.relu(embedded)

        if train:
            # minus 1 to eliminate <EOS>
            output = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(output, (target_batch_length - 1).cpu().numpy(),
                                                       batch_first=True)

        output, hidden = self.gru(output, hidden)
        output = self.softmax(self.out(output[0]))
        return output, hidden
```

Comment: Are you certain the model was indeed trained well? There may be a lot of tweaking involved in training a natural language model to a level it's able to make useful prediction

Comment: No matter how I decrease the learning rate, the loss didn't decrease at all.

Comment: Right. So apparently the network was not able to actually perform any learning, thus the results do not make any sense. If the issue you have is with *training* the network, you may want to rephrase your question and/or provide additional data (e.g. properties of your train set like its size and compostion, some abstract description of the network you're trying to train and/ or where you took it from, etc.)

Comment: and how the encoder and decoder are connected? via the last hidden state of the encoder? the hidden state value you printed, is it the last hidden states of the encoder?